# Discord.py new member message

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have this to make a welcome message for new members.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel('channel_id')
    await channel.send("insert message")
```

Does this work on bots? And will this work if the person joining is a real user?

Comment: From the documentation it appears that a `Member` includes both bots and users among many other things, please see: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: that [`bot.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel) takes `int` not `str`, if you've passed `int` then kindly check if you've enabled [Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents) for your bot in developers page and in your code.

On developers page: `https://discord.com/developers/applications/{bot_id}/bot` Enable server members intent in Privileged Gateway Intents.

On your code:

```py
intents = discord.intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)
```

Comment: I forgot to enable intents. Thank  you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will respond to bots. Bots are actually a normal user, they just have a special status.

If you want to filter out bots, then just look at the member object, it contains a property that will tell you if it is a robot - [member.bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.bot).

So then you can write something like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if not member.bot:
        channel = bot.get_channel('channel_id')
        await channel.send("insert message")
```

*Edit PS:
I recommend making a test discord server if you don't have it yet, and you can test it directly.*

*And to test people's connections, simply leave it open to people without an account, and open the server invitation in an anonymous browser window.*

Comment: I don't acutally want to exclude bots atm. I'm testing it and it doesn't work, just the classic discord welcome message.